# Mailgun - Attachments not sent via routes

Tags: php, routes, attachment, webhooks, mailgun

I'm trying to grab attachments from 'Routes', however they are not being sent. The logs are showing that there are attachments, but the route does not. I had been able to get attachments by doing something similar to this....

```
foreach($_FILES as $k => $v) {    
  // code    
}
```

...however this no longer works and the field 'attachment-count' equals 0.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: is this a forward action to your server?

Comment: Yes. To be specific, it's using the Mailgun store functionality